# ramda compose function retuns simply an Array of functions

Tags: ramda.js

I am trying to convert this functions calls to a compose function
But I I use `R.compose` and write my functions from right-to-left I simply get a function array if I try to execute the composed function.

```
R.sort((a,b) => b - a, R.keys(R.groupBy( t => t.days, holidays) ))
```

Comment: I don't see a call to `compose` in there.  Can you explain what you're trying to do and supply sample input data and the expected output to match?

Answer (score 0):

```
const x = R.compose( R.sort((a,b) => b-a) ,R.keys, R.groupBy( t => t.tage) )
```